# SQL UPDATE saving expression NOT updating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have what should be a very simple statement in my stored procedure to increment the value by +10.  However, if I run the SP more than once the value does not change after this first call.  When I modifiy the increment value to +20 the resulting table values are +20 from the ORIGINAL values set in the table.

```
USE [DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateCareerRankFromInterviewByID](
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @studentID int
    )
AS
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM StudentCategoryRankTable
    WHERE   studentID = @studentID

    INSERT INTO StudentCategoryRankTable (studentID, occupationalCategoryID, categoryWeightedTotal)
    SELECT studentID, occupationalCategoryID, SUM(weightedResponse) AS weightedResponseTotal
    FROM            dbo.weightedInterviewResponsesView
    GROUP BY studentID, occupationalCategoryID
    HAVING        (studentID = @studentID)
    ORDER BY weightedResponseTotal DESC

    -- Determine whether the student only wants to pursue
    DECLARE @certificateOnlyQuestionOptionID INTEGER = 250
    DECLARE @highMathQuestionOptionID INTEGER = 43
    DECLARE @highReadingQuestionOptionID INTEGER = 47
    DECLARE @highWritingQuestionOptionID INTEGER = 51

    DECLARE @certificateOnlyOptionAnswered INTEGER = NULL
    DECLARE @highMathQuestionOptionAnswered INTEGER = NULL
    DECLARE @highReadingQuestionOptionAnswered INTEGER = NULL
    DECLARE @highWritingQuestionOptionAnswered INTEGER = NULL

    -- Returns 0 if the 
    EXEC @certificateOnlyOptionAnswered = dbo.choseQuestionOptionID @studentID = @studentID, @questionOptionID = @certificateOnlyQuestionOptionID
    EXEC @highMathQuestionOptionAnswered = dbo.choseQuestionOptionID @studentID = @studentID, @questionOptionID = @highMathQuestionOptionID
    EXEC @highReadingQuestionOptionAnswered = dbo.choseQuestionOptionID @studentID = @studentID, @questionOptionID = @highReadingQuestionOptionID
    EXEC @highWritingQuestionOptionAnswered = dbo.choseQuestionOptionID @studentID = @studentID, @questionOptionID = @highWritingQuestionOptionID


    -- Determine if the student only wants a certificate / non-degree
    IF @certificateOnlyOptionAnswered != 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.TesterTable (TestColumn) VALUES ('Certificate True')

        -- High Math, add weight to scores for
            --  3: Business
            --  5: Computer Technologies
            --  7: Engineering Technology
            -- 18: Sciences and Math
        IF @highMathQuestionOptionAnswered != 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.TesterTable (TestColumn) VALUES ('High Math')

            UPDATE  dbo.StudentCategoryRankTable
            SET     categoryWeightedTotal += 10
            WHERE   studentID = @studentID AND
                        occupationalCategoryID IN (3, 5, 7, 18)
        END

        -- High Reading/Writing, add weight to scores for
            --  4: Communications
            -- 10: Humanities
            -- 19: Social and Behavioral Sciences
        IF @highReadingQuestionOptionAnswered != 0 OR @highWritingQuestionOptionAnswered != 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.TesterTable (TestColumn) VALUES ('High Reading/Writing')

            UPDATE  dbo.StudentCategoryRankTable
            SET     categoryWeightedTotal += 10
            WHERE   studentID = @studentID AND
                        (occupationalCategoryID = 4 OR
                         occupationalCategoryID = 10 OR
                         occupationalCategoryID = 19)
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.TesterTable (TestColumn) VALUES ('Failed Certificate Only')
    END
END
```

Comment: You might simplify your expression by using `AND oCategoryID IN (3,5,7,18)`

Comment: Thank you for the SQL advice regarding the OR section.  Same result however

Comment: Add a GO statement after the first update, so it gets committed

Comment: Do you get any results if you execute `SELECT * FROM dbo.StudentRankTable WHERE studentID = @studentID AND
  oCategoryID IN (3, 5, 7, 18)`?

Comment: @RADAR This is inside a sp, so adding a `GO` (which is a batch separator for SSMS) doesn't make sense

Comment: Is this the full SP? Is this UPDATE inside a transaction?

Comment: Yes.  I am using another query window to review results.  They are just not changing from the original value + 10

Comment: @ByronFerguson Please post the full code of the sp, there can be some logic inside that makes it so the `UPDATE` doesn't execute the same time. Is the sp being executed simultaneously?

Comment: The INSERT INTO execute just fine, and are only there is a quick and dirty debugging tool

Comment: the IF statements have BEGIN ... END blocks, and the INSERT INTO is executed.  Also, if I change the +10 to +20 the values change in the SELECT query to review the data.  However the base value is never replaced

Comment: @ByronFerguson You are first deleting the rows and then inserting them again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure you posted first removes all the entries in your `StudentCategoryRankTable` then inserts new ones. Those new records are updated. If you run the procedure again, it will `DELETE` the updated records and you will be back where you started.

Comment: I'm chalking this up to it being my birthday, and I'm another year older.

Comment: Well HAPPY BIRTHDAY! :)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm more senile today than yesterday I guess.